How can we maintain snowflake python stored procedure from vs code?
I have written some python stored procedures in snowflake. Can I maintain this stored procedures within visual studio code IDE. I need to do the following.

See code changes
Modify stored procedure from vs code
Ability to deploy stored procedures from vs code to snowflake.

Any help is appreciated!
As of now I am unable to find a solution.

Can you move the procedure to GitHub? The thing you are describing is what is called versioning. If you need to share with your team or other people and protect the store procedures, you may want to consider an Enterprise license

Integrating Snowflake with Git is covered here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/git/git-overview

You can download the GitLab/GitHub extension depending upon what you want to use for your version control and also download the Snowflake extension to execute your queries /procedure i Snowflake from Visual Studio. to store the file.
The screen shot of the UI with Git and Snowflake extension in Visual studio as below.


I tried Snowflake extension but it does not allow me to edit the snowflake stored procedures like I can in Snowpark worksheets. Is there any extension to edit stored procedures from vs code.
Thank you.

you will have create a file, store it  locally (in the Git path folder) and then you can edit/ execute on the server, you will not be able to edit directly in Snowflake.

I found an approach to continue development in vs code and deploy the Python script as stored procedure in Snowflake.
I needed to use the cproc() method provided in the snowflake snowpark package:
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import sproc

Then we can use this function to register the Python function as snowflake stored procedure like this.
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import sproc

def add_two_number(sp_session : Session, input_1 : int , input_2 : int) -> str:    
    return input_1 + input_2
  

sess.sproc.register(func=add_two_number, is_permanent=True, stage_location="@procedure",name="add_two_number", replace=True)

Reference: Sproc: A Powerful Tool for Creating Python Stored Procedures in Snowflake

@double-beep Thank you for the wonderful edit.
